# Cannot Access Computer via Private IP Address on WiFi

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I'm attempting to finish my Plex setup but I'm having an issue where my local network cannot access Plex unless the computer accessing the network is plugged directly into the Ethernet switch.

The issue started when I swapped from using the Aumox 5-Port Gigabit Network Switch to a Netgear AX1800 router in AP mode (I took all the ethernet cables plugged into the switch and moved them to the router). All computers not plugged into the router then lost access to the private IP of the computer hosting Plex.

Since then, I've disconnected the router and moved all cables back to the switch but the issue is still occurring. I disabled UFW on the host computer. I tried devices connected to Ethernet but not the switch. I've completely unplugged the router so only the original WiFi network remains. I've also tried hosting a bare NGINX server on the host computer but the issue is consistent with NGINX as well. I've also tried rebooting the host computer as well as computers I was testing from.

The host computer has been assigned a static private IP through the ATT router (it says DHCP allocation next to it but shows 192.168.1.64 as the assigned IP).

Any help would be appreciated. Using ATT as the ISP. Ideally, I'd be able to plug the router back in to use as an access point again.

Comment: Can other computers `arping` the host's address? Can they `ping` the IP? Whether they get a ping response or not, does the IP show up in their ARP cache (`ip neigh` or `arp -a`)? Does the host receive the incoming ping requests (as shown by `tcpdump -n -e -i eth0 "icmp"`)? If it receives them, does it attempt to send replies out? Does the host accidentally have _multiple_ interfaces configured for the same IP address, or at least the same subnet (e.g. ethernet and wi-fi)?

Comment: @user1686 Using arping homebrew package (have to test this from my Mac), `arp 192.168.1.64` returns the proper MAC address for the host computer. The IP also shows up in `arp -a`. The host does not appear to receive any of the incoming ping requests, and other computers fail their ping requests. 

The wlo1 interface (I'm assuming wireless) has the IP address 192.168.1.252, and enp6s0 interface (I'm assuming Ethernet) has the IP address 192.168.1.64 (this is the one I configured through the router).

Comment: Tried on a Ubuntu machine sharing the same network (machine is ethernet connected to a wireless extender) - same result as the Mac.